# Dificuldade em salvar o estado do checkbox com AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, asyncstorage

Estou com um erro ao salvar o estado de checkbox com AsyncStorage.
Ao sair/recarregar a tela, o primeiro checkbox sempre fica marcado e a marcação dos outros é retirada https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmbtl.jpg

Preciso que as caixas marcadas sejam salvas em AsyncStorage e ao recarregar o app, as caixas que foram marcadas anteriormente sejam carregas e mostradas ao usuário, não estou conseguindo encontrar a solução.
O meu código está assim:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { View, CheckBox } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

//styles
import { Container, Text, DeleteItem } from './styles';

function TaskList({ data, handleDelete }) {

  const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);

 //buscando todas as caixas ao iniciar o app
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadBox() {
      const boxStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@checkBox');

      if (boxStorage !== null) {
        setSelection(JSON.parse(boxStorage));
      }
    }
    loadBox();
  }, []);

 //salva caso tenha alguma caixa alterada
  useEffect(() => {
    async function saveBox() {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@checkBox', JSON.stringify(isSelected));
    }
    saveBox();
  }, [isSelected]);

  return (
    <Animatable.View useNativeDriver animation="bounceIn">
      <Container>
        <View>
          <CheckBox value={isSelected} onValueChange={setSelection} />
          <Text>{data.task}</Text>
        </View>
        <DeleteItem onPress={() => handleDelete(data)}>
          <Ionicons name="ios-trash" size={30} color="#FA6C30" />
        </DeleteItem>
      </Container>
    </Animatable.View>
  );
}

export default TaskList;
```

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar como? Estou um pouco confuso nesta parte aqui. Agradeço. 
O código está em: https://github.com/PlayerNumber2/app-de-tarefas

Comment: Primeiro vc precisa deixar claro na sua pergunta, qual ação que quer fazer ao checar, na sua pergunta não ficou muito claro o que você pretende fazer, segundo, eu notei que vc criou dois useEffect, que na prática sabemos que isso é errado no react, [hook effect](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), vc está reescrevendo a função useEffect.

Comment: Editei a pergunta... Preciso que as caixas marcadas sejam salvas em AsyncStorage e ao recarregar o app, as caixas que foram marcadas anteriormente sejam carregas e mostradas ao usuário.
Eu não sabia que dois useEffect é errado, obg!

Comment: Não tem problema usar 2 `useEffects`. O problema aí é que você está salvando no AsyncStorage sempre como `@checkBox`, você precisa de um `id` para cada uma para poder salvar e recuperar direito. Ou mesmo salvar a lista direto ao invés de um registro para cada checkbox, por exemplo: `[{ "id1": "true", "id2": "false" }]` .